# Is required to only check up to (num/2+1) to determine if a number if prime?

Tags: c++, primes

I have successfully coded such a program to complete this task, however my friend and I are currently having a debate over one of the values.

Here is HIS loop function:

```
for (int iii = 2; iii < (num / 2 + 1); iii++)
{
    if (num%iii == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

My question to him is, "Why do you need "2+1"?" Can't he just use his declared variable "num"?

Comment: Both of proposals are incorrect and result in wasted work. See [Prime number: Trial Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division).

Comment: *"Is there anything I can do to get rid of the "return 0;" in the bottom half of my code"* easy -- indent it at least 4 spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to check up to `sqrt(num)`, which is less than or equal `num/2` for `num >= 4`. This is because if a number `n > sqrt(num)` divides `num`, then `num/n < sqrt(num)` divides `num`.

*Proof of that claim:*

The square root of a positive number `n` is defined as the unique positive real number `x` for which `x * x == n` holds. Now consider you have a divisor `d` of `n` such that `d > n`. Then there is (because `d` is a divisor) a natural number `d2` such that `d * d2 == n`. It is obvious that `d2 := n / d` is such a number. From `x * x == n`, `d * d2 == n` and `d > x` one can conclude `d2 < x`. That means that if a number greater than `x` divides `n`, there also is a number less than `x` that also divides day. So in conclusion, if no number less or equal `x` divides `n`, `n` is prime.

That means the function is correct for all values greater or equal 2. For `num >= 4` this follows immediately from the above. For `num <= 1` your function will alway return `true` because the loop never executes. For `2 <= num <=3` the loop returns `true` correctly because again, the loop is never entered. (Technically, you need the `+1` to proof 5 is prime because `5/2=2 < sqrt(5)` because of integer division).

Comment: @Tanner: It works, but it's still (well) short of optimal. After checking that the number isn't even, you know that no other even number can divide into it either, so you normally want to skip those as well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I guess I just have trouble understanding how the square root is actually working; that is why I took the simple (longer un-optimal) path.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I get why I should use the square root function instead....but I do not get "Why" it works and "how"

Comment: @Tanner I'll further edit my answer to better explain why the square root approach works.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I think I understand why Square root works now, if you could rewrite this "for (int iii = 2; iii < (num / 2 + 1); iii++)" Using your method, what would you write? Thanks so much

Comment: @Tanner That's trivial, loop while `iii < sqrt(num)`. You can do that yourself.

Comment: That should be `iii <= sqrt(num)`, no?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thank you so much for your help! Is there a way to get rid of these Return 0;'s that I edited into my initial post

Comment: @Tanner One question per question please. That's dem Rulez. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement:

- You could test with 2, and avoid all the other even numbers.
- You only need to test until sqrt(number), already explained in other answer.

Code:

```
#include <cmath>

bool is_prime(unsigned long number) {
    if (number % 2 == 0 && number != 2)
        return false;
    unsigned long sqrt_number = static_cast<unsigned long>(std::sqrt(number));
    for (unsigned long i = 3; i <= sqrt_number; i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is implementing a "prime number" test. A number is prime if it is not divisible by any whole number other than itself and 1.

This problem space has some well known parameters/factors.

a) The maximum value that any given number, N, can be divided by to produce an integer value is N/2.
b) If N is divisible by an even number, it will also be divisible by 2, i.e. it must be even.

```
is_prime(N) {
    if is_even(N) {
       // if N is 2, it's prime, otherwise
       // any even number is divisible by
       // 2 and thus not prime.
       return (N == 2)
    }

    md = max_divisor(N)

    // we've eliminated even numbers, so we need only
    // test odd numbers.
    // all numbers are divisible by 1, so start at 3.
    for (divisor = 3; divisor <= md; divisor += 2) {
      // determine whether divisor divides into N
      // without remainder indicating non-prime N
      remainder = (N % divisor)
      if (remainder != 0)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

The max divisor is a number that, when divided into N, will produce 2.

```
max_divisor * 2 = N  ->
max_divisor = N / 2
```

So simply:

```
max_divisor(N) return N / 2
```

What about checking for even numbers? We can do this one of two ways. We can modulo 2, but many people trying to optimize there code will remember their binary logical and realize they just have to test if the lowest bit (bit 1) is set or not.

```
0001 = 1 (odd)
0010 = 2 (even)
0011 = 3 (odd)
0100 = 4 (even)
0101 = 5 (odd)
0110 = 6 (even)
0111 = 7 (odd)
```

very simple:

```
is_even(N) (N % 2) == 0
or
is_even(N) (N & 1) == 0
```

And converting to C:

```
static inline bool isEven(unsigned int number) {
    return (number & 1) == 0;
}

static inline unsigned int maxDivisor(unsigned int number) {
    return (number / 2);
}

unsigned int isPrime(unsigned int number) {
    if (isEven(number)) {
       // if N is 2, it's prime, otherwise
       // any even number is divisible by
       // 2 and thus not prime.
       // fluffy expanded version
       return (number == 2) ? true : false;
       // compact version
       // return (number == 2);
    }

    const unsigned int md = maxDivisor(number);

    // we've eliminated even numbers, so we need only
    // test odd numbers.
    // all numbers are divisible by 1, so start at 3.
    for (unsigned int divisor = 3; divisor <= md; divisor += 2) {
      // determine whether divisor divides into number
      // without remainder indicating non-prime number
      const unsigned int remainder = (number % divisor);
      if (remainder != 0)
        return false;
      // compact version:
      //if (number % divisor)
      //  return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Your friend's "(N / 2) + 1" is because he is using a less-than rather than a <=, you could remove the "+1" in his code by writing the following:

```
for (int iii = 2; iii <= (num / 2); iii++)
```